# program in any language Numerical methods

Tags: numerical-methods

To estimate the absolute and relative error of the calculation of the F value under
condition of:

- A) the given exact numbers of the entered values of the arguments are *x<sub>1</sub> , x<sub>2</sub> , x<sub>3</sub>*
- B) the given values of arguments *x<sub>1</sub> , x<sub>2</sub> , x<sub>3</sub>* with the error *ϵ = N⋅10<sup>-3</sup>*, where *N* is the
  variant number

#### Variant 1

> *F = 2⋅x<sub>1</sub> <sup>2</sup> + 3⋅x<sub>2</sub> <sup>2</sup> + x<sub>3</sub> <sup>2</sup> + 4⋅x<sub>1</sub>⋅x<sub>2</sub> – 3⋅x<sub>3</sub> + cos(x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>)*

#### Variant 2

> *F = 5⋅x<sub>1</sub> <sup>2</sup> + 3⋅x<sub>2</sub> <sup>2</sup> + 2⋅x<sub>3</sub> <sup>2</sup> - 4⋅x<sub>2</sub>⋅x<sub>3</sub> - 2⋅x<sub>1</sub> – cos(x<sub>2</sub>⋅x<sub>3</sub>);*

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: What did you try? Why do you think this is a programming problem? Can you do this task if you take only one or two terms of the given expressions? A more suitable forum for this kind of question is http://scicomp.stackexchange.com, where you and answerers also have mathjax support for more ease in writing formulas.